# looking to create a new row that has one additional column

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image: DB structure]

i want from above table 
we get:

```
19  |  6E-SF-TYPE  | Fixed |   0 | ServiceFee | 1
19  |  6ES-SF-TYPE | Fixed | 100 | ServiceFee | 1
19  |  9H-SF-TYPE  | Fixed |   0 | ServiceFee | 1
```

I hope that it would be clear that i am adding the value of that type. 
I cant change my db structure for this.

looking to create a new row that has one additional column. I want the preferenceValue from row 2 to be the 4th value in new row. Otherwise I want row 1 normal values.

Comment: Is there any "Value" column prepared for the issue?

Comment: Looks to me like you do not want to `Combine` rows, rather you are looking to create a new row that has one additional column.  You want the `preferenceValue` from `row 2` to be the `4th` value in your new row.  Otherwise you want `row 1` normal values?

Comment: @Rohit Ok, that is what I figured, and it looks like codingbiz has your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

[See the result in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/121c0/2) This should do. You simply join the table to itself using the prefix for the value and type which are the same after removing the -TYPE and -VALUE suffix. In the query, `t` represents type and `v` represents value

```
Select 
   t.memberid, 
   t.preferencekey, 
   v.preferencevalue, 
   t.category, 
   t.itemtypeid 
from @t t
JOIN 
(
    Select * From @t t
    Where CHARINDEX('-VALUE', t.preferencekey) > 0
) v
ON REPLACE(t.preferencekey,'-TYPE','') = REPLACE(v.preferencekey,'-VALUE','')
Where CHARINDEX('-TYPE', t.preferencekey) > 0
```

### Output

```
19  6E-SF-TYPE  0   Service Fee 1
19  6ES-SF-TYPE 100 Service Fee 1
19  9H-SF-TYPE  0   Service Fee 1
```

Comment: Add `,t.preferencevalue AS 'Fixed'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.memberid, t1.preferencekey, 
t1.preferencevalue, t2.preferenceValue, 
t1.category, t1.itemTypeId
FROM tablename t1
JOIN tablename t2 on t1.memberid = t2.memberid 
    AND t2.preferenceKey = replace(t1.preferenceKey, 'TYPE', 'VALUE')
WHERE t1.preferenceKey like '%TYPE'
```